# Is it safe to cook and eat raw meat that a stray cat was eating?

Tags: cats, safety, diseases, strays

If a stray cat is eating raw hamburger meat, can I still cook and eat it afterwards? Would it be safe, considering that the stray cat was eating from it?

Comment: Hi Tammy and welcome to Pets SE, I modified the title so it's more catchy for people's attention, I removed tag "health" because it's about health concerns in pets and not in humans, and removed "cooked-food" because it's about preparing cooked food for pets and not humans, I added "safety" and "diseases".

Comment: I'm confused. What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to eat the hamburger meat that was lying around for whatever reason? Or are you trying to cook the cat? In either way: What? Why?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with pets. Any sane human will tell you it's not safe to eat random raw meat that wasn't refridgerated for who knows how long. Whether or not a cat stole a bite is completely irrelevant.

Comment: How could you get the meat from a stray cat once he has his fangs in it? It is unsafe to try to get the meat away from such a cat, let alone cook it. Unless, of course you are preparing for Hunger Games :)